# Why can a Predictive Parser contain E' -> TE' | ε

Tags: parsing, compilers, recursion

I am studying the basics of predictive parsing and I think I have missed a concept that I would like to understand instead of just accepting and memorizing. I am watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgpcZ825ddM&t=3m44s) and I am confused as to why

`E' -> TE' | ε` is valid

because

`E -> E + T` is not valid since we have "left recursion" (a variable that calls itself).

in other words, why doesn't `E' -> TE' | ε` or `T' -> *FT'` have left recursion? To me it looks a lot like `E'` and `T'` are calling themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... is not valid since we have "left recursion" (a variable that calls itself).

That's not what a *left* recursion is. That's simply recursion.

*Direct* left recursion is when a rule $A \to A\alpha$ exists for arbitrary $\alpha$.

*Indirect* left recursion exists when there's a rule $A \to^* A\alpha$ for arbitrary $\alpha$. Note the star, implying possibly many derivation steps (and if we're being precise, more than one, otherwise it's just direct left recursion).

Only **left** recursion (whether indirect or direct) is problematic for $\text{LL}(1)$. But your grammar doesn't contain left recursion, only right recursion. Right recursion has the form $A\to^* \alpha A$. See the difference?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will study this soon and reply back in about 4-7 hours.